# Como modificar CSS dinamicamente utilizando PHP

Tags: php, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Preciso modificar alguns estilos CSS de acordo com uma condição em PHP, então dei uma pesquisada, e pelo que vi é necessário incluir um cabeçalho no arquivo CSS e mudar o arquivo `.css` para `.php`, ou então criar um arquivo htacess (mas onde? onde?)... mas acho que por serem antigos, estes artigos estão desatualizados com alguma (ou todas, ou nenhuma :D) as versões do PHP, da CSS, do Apache ou do Bootstrap que estou usando, ou então o mais provável, que seja apenas eu fazendo algo errado mesmo.

O caso é que eu montei estes painéis com `nav-tabs` do Bootstrap:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading" align="center">
                    <label class="btn" id="cdom">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
                        </i>&nbsp; Título</label></div>
                           <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Resumo</a></li>
                                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Entenda</a></li>                                   
                            </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                Seção A
                            </div>
                            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <h5>Section B</h5>
                            </div>                               
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div> <div class="col-md-8></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

E já consegui mudar a cor do `panel-header` escapando o HTML, de acordo com uma condição.

```
 <div class="panel <?php if ($var1 > 60000){echo 'panel-success';}else {echo 'panel-danger';}?> bs-example" align="center">
```

Mas agora preciso alterar também a CSS da `nav-tab`, de acordo com a mesma condição. Já tentei fazer com `span`, mas não deu certo. E já mudei o nome do arquivo CSS, inclui o `header` e chamei o `.php` onde está a variável, mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

O CSS atual `style.php`:

```
<?php header('Content-type:text/css');
include "../saida.php";
?>

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    color: #020202;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: <?php if ($var1 > 60000){echo '#0e7363';}else {echo '#f2dede';}?> ;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;

}
```

Mas ele continua não alterando a cor de acordo com a condição.

> **A pergunta**

Como fazer para incluir script PHP no arquivo CSS, **sem ter que alterar para `.php`**, ou seja, utilizando o `htacess` ou o equivalente, e como incluir o PHP dentro do CSS (está correta a forma que estou fazendo?)?

Comment: Não é mais fácil apenas alterar o retorno do php com classes css diferentes de acordo com a situação?

Comment: Sim, pode ser com classe, de acordo com a condição do php, mas de qualquer forma eu também queria aprender a utilizar o php dentro da CSS. Valeu.

Comment: Que eu saiba, nao tem como você aplicar um arquivo php sem a extençao .php. oque eu acho viável eh voce aplicar o estilo css no cabeçao da sua index.php. Ou fazer como disse o @EduardoSilva

Comment: @EduardoSilva http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65154/como-criar-classes-css-contendo-outras-classes-do-bootstrap

Comment: Consegui resolver com classes conforme a resposta do @EduardoSilva [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65154/como-criar-classes-css-contendo-outras-classes-do-bootstrap), mas ainda tenho a dúvida sobre a forma correta e até a segurança de se incluir PHP num arquivo CSS. Segundo um comentário [nesta pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8977446/4734177) no SOen "Echoing unsanitized input leaves the door open for injection attacks via malcrafted URLs.". Editei a pergunta (inclusive o título) pra incluir a questão da segurança.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como disse no comentário, ao carregar uma folha de estilo mesmo com HTACCESS, os parâmetros não transitam, no máximo passe via GET uma ULR como: `<link ... href="localhost/php.css?parametro=XXX">`

Para não ter exposição de dados tão clara e melhorar o parâmetro, vou usar `base64_encode` e `base64_decode` na variável `$_GET` no arquivo que de folha de estilo, junto com `parse_str` para criar um array com os atributos.

Para fins de teste basta alterar `background=f3f3f3` pelo valor que quiser. O Ideone não permite HTACCESS, então não há como dispor um exemplo online, mas a execução foi feita como você deseja.

---

<sub>**HTACCESS**</sub>

```
RewriteRule ^home/         /test.php
RewriteRule ^style/php.css /style.php
```

<sub>**PHP**</sub>

```
<?php
$argument = base64_encode( 'background=f3f3f3' );
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://localhost/style/php.css?argument=<?php echo $argument;?>">
```

<sub>**CSS**</sub>

```
<?php
parse_str( base64_decode( $_GET['argument'] ) , $output );
?>

*{background:#<?php echo $output['background'] ;?>}
```

---

O `HTACCESS` está aceitando a URL `http://localhost/home/`, não incrementei muito pra deixar o mais didático possível. Só precisa criar `test.php` e `style.php`.

Perceba que `RewriteRule ^style/php.css /style.php` seria como uma regra exclusiva para quando você apontar o caminho para `style/php.css` executar sempre `style.php` sem que outras folhas de estilo sejam redirecionadas.

Comment: Valeu @PapaCharlie Vou estudar melhor esta solução, que acredito que soluciona a pergunta completamente (falta apenas a qustão da segurança de usar o php dentro do CSS, mas como sugeriu o gmsantos, acho que é melhor fazer esta pergunta em outro tópico). +1

Comment: @gustavox, são parâmetros irrelevantes, não vejo problema de segurança nesse caso.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei qual sua necessidade em mudar o CSS via PHP, já tive este pensamento em um projeto, e o fiz como está querendo. Porem  não é recomendado fazer assim e nem o certo.

Aconselho dar uma olhada em JavaScript, Jquery.
Voce conseguiria fazer isso em apenas uma linha por ex:

```
$(".nav-tabs > li.active > a").on('click', function(){
    $(this).css({'css', '#0e7363'});
});
```

Usando isso você pode modificar o CSS tanto no PHP como direto no HTML etc..

Documentação Jquery: http://jquery.com/

Como usar para manipulação de CSS: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Mas eu preciso que ele observe uma condição em PHP, de uma variável do PHP. No caso eu tenho esta variável $var1 de um script PHP, que é resultado de um cálculo feito à partir de outras variáveis, que vem de um formulário. Então, se $var > 0, deve usar uma cor de CSS, se $var < 0, outra cor. Não vejo como resolver isso com JS ou jQuery, mas agradeço a dica, embora ainda não seja o que estou procurando, acho que vai ser útil pra outra coisa. :-) +1

Comment: Da sim, só você jogar um script Jquery dentro da sua função PHP.
Qualquer coisa voce faz essa conta em Javascript então...