# Mudar o CSS com sessão e divs desalinhadas

Tags: php, html, css

De modo geral, como mudar a propriedade CSS de alguma tag dependendo do acesso do usuário ao sistema?

Abaixo está a imagem do cabeçalho (rascunho) antes do usuário acessar ao sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E abaixo o mesmo cabeçalho, mas com as divs dos botões desalinhadas (desconsidere o tamanho exagerado do nome do usuário):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E abaixo estão os códigos dos dois:

```
<div class="header">
<h1 style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: 0px;"><a href="index.php">TI_sem_dúvidas</a></h1>
<div class="btn_login" style="margin-left: 1000px; margin-top: 50px;">
    <a href="#abrir-modal">Login</a>
</div>
```

Acima foi o header antes do login.

Abaixo é o de depois.

```
<div class="header">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 300px; margin-top: 0px;"><a href="index.php">TI_sem_dúvidas</a></h1>
    <div class="btn_login" style="margin-left: 800px; margin-top: 50px; background-color: steelblue; width: 300px;">
        Nome de Usuário
    </div>
    <div class="btn_login" style="margin-left: 1000px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <a href="#abrir-modal">Sair</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo está o css do HTML e do body

```
   html{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

    body{
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 0 0 400px; /* bottom = footer height */
    }
```

Os cabeçalhos têm a extensão `html.php`.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas não é o caso de `if( ... ) else`?

Comment: @PapaCharlie vc diz colocar o if else do php dentro do HTML ou do  CSS? Pergunto porque fiz esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65104/como-modificar-com-seguran%C3%A7a-um-arquivo-css-utilizando-php (ainda sem resposta) e me pareceu insegura a utilização de php dentro do CSS, por causa de uma resposta que vi no SOen...

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer carregar uma nova folha de estilos de acordo com a autenticação de um usuário (ou seja, alguém 'conectou-se' e assim muda o CSS), correto? Se sim, acho que se você incrementar um HTML por meio PHP (um `echo` do conteúdo HTML) que tenha um script JavaScript para alterar o estilo dos elementos necessários resolverá seu problema. E se for autenticação com Ajax, mais fácil ainda! Basta inserir mais linha de código JavaScript na chamada de função! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Vejamos

Acredito que existem várias maneiras de se resolver seu problema - o de carregar outra folha de estilos - mas vou citar apenas duas formas que me veio logo a mente. Mas, primeiro, preciso dizer que suponho que você esteja usando PHP devido as TAGs que atribui à sua pergunta no *SOPT*. E suponho que a autenticação de usuário também seja em PHP.

---

### 1º - Caso *não* seja autenticação que utilize Ajax

Vou supor que você esteja fazendo algo do tipo quanto a autenticação:

- *Página 1 - com o formulário de login*
- *Página 2 - de autenticação (PHP)*
- *Página 3 - destino*

Você poderia criar cookies e fazer um `IF()`/`ELSE` com PHP para verificar quando carregar um arquivo CSS. Algo do tipo:

```
<!-- PÁGINA 1 = PÁGINA 3 -->
<head>
...
<?php
...
if(!isset($_COOKIE['css']) && $_COOKIE['css'] == "css")
     echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./novo_estilo.css" />';
else
     echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./antigo_estilo.css" />';
...
?>
...
</head>
```

Esse cookie será configurado na página 2.

```
<?php
// PÁGINA 2 - PHP - Autenticador
...
$cookie_nome = "css";
$cookie_valor = "css";
$cookie_tempo = 86400; // No caso, um dia mas você deve alterar

setcookie($cookie_nome, $cookie_valor, time() + $cookie_tempo, "/");
...
?>
```

**NOTA**: Funcionará mesmo se a página 1 for diferente da página 3 (diferentes arquivos PHP). O que muda é que ambas as páginas receberão código.

---

### 2º - Caso seja autenticação que utilize Ajax

Vou supor que você esteja fazendo algo do tipo quanto a autenticação:

- *Página 1 - com formulário de login;*
- *Página 1 - com autenticação (PHP) chamada via Ajax*
- *Página 1 - saída em algum local da mesma página de formulário;*

**Nesse caso**, quando o Ajax for jogar o conteúdo alterado na página, basta você alterar o estilo dos elementos desejados com JavaScript mesmo, sem usar um arquivo CSS para isso, logo depois de despejar a página de autenticação em algum elemento da página (`<body>`, `<div>`, etc).

**Alternativamente**, você poderá usar o primeiro método - o do *cookie*. Ele é mais *'organizado'* porém mais *'demorado'*. Este método aqui é mais *'rápido'* e mais *'enxuto'*, além de tornar *desnecessário a existência de dois arquivos CSS*. Mas quem vai escolher vai ser você.

---

Não vou dar exemplos de código pois acho que o ***JSFiddle*** não suporta Ajax ou Session ou Cookie (acho). Mas com isso que foi dito, tudo deve funcionar por aí.

**Espero ter ajudado!** ;)